# Hibernate with @CollectionTable removes the objects of set with same boolean value on update

Tags: java, hibernate, set, embeddable

I have the following structure:

```
public class Profile {
 ...

 @ElementCollection(targetClass = ProfileFieldImpl.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @CollectionTable(name = "profileField", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "profileId"))
 @OrderColumn(name = "fieldName")
 private Set<ProfileField> fields;

}

@Embeddable
public class ProfileFieldImpl {

    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "rofileFieldId", nullable = false))
    private Long profileFieldId;

    private String name;

}
```

Now i'm adding a new column: **publicField**
Added also the `equals` and `hashCode` mothods.

```
public class ProfileFieldImpl {

    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "rofileFieldId", nullable = false))
    private Long profileFieldId;

    private String name;

    private boolean publicField;

    @Override
    public final boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (o == this) {
            return true;
        } else if (o == null || !(o instanceof ProfileFieldImpl)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            final ProfileFieldImpl other = (ProfileFieldImpl) o;
            return EqualsUtil.equalsNullable(getName(), other.getName()) && EqualsUtil.equalsNullable(isPublicField(), other.isPublicField()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {
        return HashCodeUtil.seed(HashCodeUtil.SEED_13).with(name).with(publicField).hashCode();
    }
}
```

Adding the following fields (Database fields):

```
1. name = "Field1", publicField = '0'
2. name = "Field2", publicField = '0'
3. name = "Field3", publicField = '1'
4. name = "Field4", publicField = '1'
```

How I do the update:

```
....
final ProfileImpl profile = getEntityManager().find(Profile.java, profileId, LockModeType.NONE);
final Set<ProfileField> fields = profile.getFields();

fields.stream().filter(field -> field.getName().equals(currentFieldName)).forEach(field -> {
    field.setName(updatedProfileField.getName());
    field.setPublicField(updatedProfileField.isPublicField());
});

getEntityManager().merge(profile);
```

**The Issue:**

When I'm trying to update the `field3`, the `field4` is deleted;
When I'm trying to update the `field1`, the `field2` is deleted.

Do someone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the **issue** and also the **solution**.

Because of using boolean as `primitive` instead of `object` was that issue.

Solution was to use the Boolean wrapper instead of the primitive.

```
private Boolean publicField;
```

Now is working properly without removing any other object.

Comment: It still sound like a bug. You should create a Hibernate Jira issue

Comment: I will open an issue soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bug. So you need to:

- provide a [replicating test case](http://in.relation.to/2016/01/14/hibernate-jpa-test-case-template/)
- open a Jira issue

Comment: I updated the post and also found the issue. Thank you for support!